# FBSnapshotTestCase image not found while running Xcode test

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, fbsnapshottestcase

Can't figure out why report `FBSnapshotTestCase image not found while running Xcode test`.

I tried to link `FBSnapshotTestCase` in Target `ChartTests`, but still seeing the same error.

I am not familiar with this, can anyone help? Thank in advance.

To reproduce:

Download the project from https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

navigate to the project root,

1. (optional) run `carthage bootstrap` to install dependency. The project has a dependency check, so if you don't run this, it will run it when launching the test.
2. enter

   > xcodebuild -project 'Charts.xcodeproj' -scheme 'ChartsTests' -configuration 'Debug' -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id='E40B5365-EF82-430D-A767-2A37995CCEE1' clean build test

the destination id could be any uuid of the simulator on the machine.

Then it reports:

```
2017-04-20 13:47:57.611 xctest[90924:13099756] The bundle “ChartsTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2017-04-20 13:47:57.611 xctest[90924:13099756] (dlopen_preflight(/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Charts-ambsdrskvocwekcmoobyhanaiixm/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChartsTests.xctest/ChartsTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSnapshotTestCase.framework/FBSnapshotTestCase
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Charts-ambsdrskvocwekcmoobyhanaiixm/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ChartsTests.xctest/ChartsTests
  Reason: image not found)
2017-04-20 13:47:57.625 xcodebuild[90311:13086990] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

Testing failed:
    Test target ChartsTests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted)
** TEST FAILED **
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I need to add run script in Build phases, and let carthage copy the frameworks:

copy from https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos:

On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script in which you specify your shell (ex: /bin/sh), add the following contents to the script area below the shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/FBSnapshotTestCase.framework
```